# Api gateway Cognito User Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I need help! I am trying manager access of api gateway by cognito.

- I create an api gateway, auth by cognito
- In cognito, I create an group with deny access to api method
- I authenticated by cognito, and return group in idToken

**PROBLEM: I still can access this api, why? How `Cognito auth` work in api gateway?**

Comment: Did you deploy your latest API Gateway changes to the stage?

Comment: Yes MaikaY, I am authenticated by JWT (TokenID)

Comment: @ClóvisJunior, Have you implemented social media signup using AWS Cognito? I'm facing issue with validate JWT Token. For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971807/how-to-get-jwt-from-facebook-credentials-using-amazon-cognito-user-pool

Answer (score 1):

up until dec-2017 cognito user pools authorization method was actually performing authentication and not authorization. There were no granular entitlements available and any authenticated user (presenting `identity token`) could invoke an endpoint resource protected with cognito user pool. For actual authorization (granular entitlements) you had to use either IAM or custom authorizers.

As per [this announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/12/amazon-api-gateway-supports-amazon-cognito-oauth2-scopes/) Cognito can now also pass `access tokens` with oauth 2 scopes. I personally haven't tried this one yet but I believe this should solve your question.

Comment: Have you implemented social media signup using AWS Cognito? I'm facing issue with validate JWT Token. For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971807/how-to-get-jwt-from-facebook-credentials-using-amazon-cognito-user-pool