# How to get JWT from Facebook credentials using Amazon Cognito user pool?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook

I've got credentials for Facebook after federated login with aws, but after successful login I was not getting any response or jwt token.

I've tried with AWS Cognito authentication and tried with AWSCognitoCredentials provider but didn't found any solution

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: AWSRegionType.USEast1, identityPoolId: "us-east-1:xxxxxxxxx", identityProviderManager: CredentialProviderClass).credentials().continueWith { (task) -> Any? in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                if (task.error != nil) {
                    print("Error : \(task.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
                } else {
                    // the task result will contain the identity id
                    if let credentials = task.result {
                        print(credentials)
                    }
                }
            }

            return nil
        }
```

I am expecting JWT token after login to Facebook with successful authentication.